# Using Rome to aggregate RSS feeds and Description not getting encoded. Why?

Tags: encoding, rss, rome

When I specify the encoding for my new feed as UTF-8 (matches my sources), my output feed has no encoding for the emdash and curly quotes.  If I specify ISO-8859-1 for encoding (but I don't want to), the characters are encoded.  How to I force it to encode for UTF-8?

Answer (score -1):

I was having the some problem when was trying to generating RSS feed in Java Servlet. Just make sure that response content encoding is equal to encoding of feed output.

```
feed.setEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```